# Why doesn't Django serialize full model relations?

Tags: python, django, json, serialization

The question is pretty simple:
I am aware that Django won't serialize the related models when using

```
serialize("json", queryset)
```

In example: If I have a book with an author:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKeyField(Author)
```

When serializing, I get the Books fields, but only the author's pk.
Why is that? Is it a design decision? If that's it, why?

Comment: It fetches the database fields. The corresponding database entries is stored as the `id` of the `ForeignKey` field

Comment: Like @karthikr says, its db related. Have a look at the dumpdata command which takes a "--natural" parameter for a more verbose way of describing relationships via the ContentTypes framework

Comment: What do you mean by dbrelated? I was expecting something in the lines of "it's hard to deserialize". Besides, if the relation is many-to-many, it has the intelligence to look in the corresponding table..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible using natural key, a custom manager and `get_by_natural_key()`. Django doc has a full explanation, please [read here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#natural-keys). I'd rather not copy paste everything here.

By using this method, you can turn the regular serialization like this -

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "store.book",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Mostly Harmless",
        "author": 42
    }
}
```

To this -

```
{
    "pk": 1,
    "model": "store.book",
    "fields": {
        "name": "Mostly Harmless",
        "author": ["Douglas", "Adams"]
    }
}
```

Comment: I read through the docs already, I'm not saying it doesn't work, but it surely isn't intuitive. Example: Now you need the author's hometown... what do you do? +1 because the docs are the best place to learn

Comment: @Alvaro you modify the `natural_key()` method to return hometown too, and then modify the `get_by_natural_key()` method to get the author using all 3 properties.